# Runlevel3 (systemd) - target on Opensuse 13.2 starts GUI

Tags: opensuse, systemd

From my understanding, setting the default target to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/runlevel3.target` should not start the GUI--but it does.

Also the file `runlevel3.target` looks exactly the same as `runlevel5.target`. Is this a known bug ?

Comment: How did you set it? The proper way is systemctl set-default multi-user.target.

Answer (score 2):

What command are you using to set the default? You can set it through the systemctl command:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Or by linking the default.target:

```
ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target' '/etc/systemd/system/default.target'
```